# Converting key-value lines of text to an array

Tags: php, explode

After making an API call I am getting back a reply body in the following format:

```
TransactionID=123456
Status=OK
SomethingElse=test
Date=2013-09-05 15:00:00
```

Is there a quicker way of getting these key-value pairs into an array than doing:

```
$data=array();

$lines=explode("\n\r",$result);

foreach($lines as $line){

    $bits=explode('=',$line);

    $data[$bits[0]]=$bits[1];
}
```

I was hoping there may be a function I'd not used before?

Comment: Your code looks good to me - it's the way I would parse it (but be frustrated the API is returning it in that format rather than JSON or XML).

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [parse_ini_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php)

As long as that's the format you should have no problems.

Comment: + Nice spot. This is hands down the right answer to this question.

Comment: Yes, perfect! Hadn't thought of this one!

Comment: Keep in mind that, as long as you have no control over the output/format that is returned, it shoud be considered bad practice to blindly rely on this function, as its output could change/break at any point in time.

Comment: @jaffog The function returns `false` on errors so I don't think this will be a problem.

Comment: Also note that you need PHP 5 >= 5.3.0 as stated in the documentation, though you will find a pretty good non-native implementation in the comments that treats a lot more exceptions than your version.

Comment: @Marc What I mean is that if the function returns `false`, this doesn't necessarily mean the key/value pair is invalid, it just means the function `parse_ini_string()` cannot deal with it. It happend to me in the past, so just wanted to warn you about it, as it caused me some serious headaches (not to mention hours of searching for that needle in the haystack).